# How to publish and host a MVC4 application in your domain?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ftp, publish

I have a webdomain www.MyDomain.com and a MVC4 web application MyMVCWebApp.

First I publish the application to a local destination.

For instance: C:\TempLocation

And then I host it to my domain with a FTP-tool (FileZilla??)

The files will be hosted but I can't find the webpage.

Which url do I have to write? 
http://www.MyDomain.com/MyMVCWebApp/Home/Index.chtml or something?!

Do I have change the settings in my web.config?

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can't host an application on a domain.

An application is hosted on a web server. A domain name is only a way to translate an easy to remember address like "www.google.com" to the web server ip address which looks like 173.194.66.104

It is possible to purchase a domain without a web server.

So before going further:

- Check if you actually bought a domain only, or a domain with a server
- Your domain should redirect to your server ip address, you can see if he is correctly configured by opening a command prompt and doing

> C:\> ping www.yourdomain.com

If this is not the case you will need to update the A record of your domain, and wait for the update to be replicated on DNS server worldwird.

- If you have a **managed server**, you should check your hosting provider website. They usually provide in depth documentation, and they all have a different way to do things. Most of the time indeed you will be able to upload your files using a FTP software such as Filezilla.

  However, in order to host a MVC 4 application you need a server with
  the IIS web server, which means that you need a Windows server. So if
  you have a Linux server, you should contact your hosting provider
  support and tell them you made a mistake during your order. *(It is
  possible to host a MVC 4 application on Linux, but I don't think it
  is often provided on managed servers)*
- If you have a **dedicated server** you are on your own.

The URL you will have to write to access your application will depends on what you have configured in the **RegisterRoutes** method of the **RouteConfigs.cs** file.

I recommend you to watch the last video on [this page](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/pluralsight-building-applications-with-aspnet-mvc-4) to have a better overview of the possibilities.

Comment: I bought a domain provider (with Linux). So I cancelled it. But can you tell me which a domain provider with a server I can take? YourHosting or Microsoft Azure?

Comment: It really depends in which country you live. Both are acceptable solutions.

Comment: please help me i want to deploy my mvc4 application on my public domain but i am getting error can you please  tell me steps.